# Get Vector3 of Position Clicked on Plane

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, physics, raycasting, mouse-position

I want to click on a 3D plane with my mouse. When I do this, I want it to return a `Vector3` of where I clicked. When I use:

```
Vector3 point = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
```

then, it gives me the `Vector3` of the center of the plane. Not what I want. I want it to be at the position I click.

I am trying to create a `Ray` (`Camera.ScreenPointToRay`) and work with `Physics.Raycast`, but that just returns a `bool`, and not where it actually hits.

I have spent the last 3 hours reading everyone else's questions...what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are almost there! What you need to use is [Plane.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html)

## Edit

```
Plane plane = blablabla;
Ray ray = blablabla;
float distance;
Vector3? intersectionPoint = null;
if (plane.Raycast(ray, out distance))
    intersectionPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);
```

Comment: No it isn't.  I am not looking for a boolean, I am looking for a Vector3.

Comment: Yes, it is. Please, be so kind and read that page through carefully: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html

Answer (score 0):

Here this should help you…

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition); //Convert mouse position to raycast
RaycastHit hit; //Create a RaycastHit variable to store the hit data into
Vector3 clickedPosition; //Create a vector3 variable to store the clicked position in

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 1000)) //If the user clicks the left mouse button and we hit an object with our raycast then
{
    clickedPosition = hit.point; //Store the hit position into the clicked position variable
}
```

It's that simple :)